# Enqueuing new GitHub Commits to Google Pub/Sub in Real-Time

Tags: github, rss, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-source-repos

I'm attempting to listen to new commits to a public GitHub repository that I do not own, and would like to push new commit events to GCP Pub/Sub such that a function can consume it further. I recognize that GitHub itself exposes RSS feeds to different event types in a given repository, and am curious about how we can process changes in real-time efficiently.

Here are two similar workflows that I thought about:

1. Routinely schedule a job to pull the RSS feed, check for new changes against what we've already seen and processed, and enqueue whatever is fresh.
2. Fork the repository, and integrate with [Cloud Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories), such that we can enqueue notifications on changes. We can then setup a [Fork Sync](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/fork-sync) action to routinely sync the forked repo itself (say, every 2-5 minutes).

My worry is that we're routinely scheduling jobs in both approaches, which may be unnecessary and potentially expensive if we're entering periods with no changes at all. Is there a much more effective approach where we can trigger processing *without* continuously polling for changes?

Comment: Have you explored on webhooks : https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/about-webhooks

Answer (score 1):

You can first mirror the [repository](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository). By doing that, "[Cloud Source Repositories automatically syncs your repository with the mirrored repository when a user commits a change](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository#force_a_repository_sync)".
Then, you can set up Cloud [Pub/Sub notifications](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/pubsub-notifications), and get notified for event "[RefUpdate](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/pubsub-notifications#event_types)".
Finally your function can consume the Pub/Sub message generated.